# How to GET data from firebase by REST via curl?

Tags: firebase, rest, url, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to [GET data from firebase by REST](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data). My firebase database looks like this

[image]

So I want to fetch it with curl:

```
curl 'https://smwtest-15295.firebaseio.com/WHAT_HERE?'
```

but I don't know what to put as request url params.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your URIs have to end with `.json`, as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data) you refer to.

For example:

```
curl 'https://smwtest-15295.firebaseio.com/9099.json'
```

or

```
curl 'https://smwtest-15295.firebaseio.com/9099/address.json'
```

Then you can [filter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-filtering) or [order](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-ordered-data) your data by adding query string parameters.

---

If you want to query the entire JSON tree, use:

```
curl 'https://smwtest-15295.firebaseio.com/.json'
```

---

More details in the [REST API Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database).

Comment: thanks a lot, I'm a little bit surprised by that  wierd "DOTjson" thing at the end

Comment: The `.json` suffix is used by Firebase to recognize REST requests. Without `.json` at the end of the URL, it would be interpreted as a request to the Firebase console. Give it a try by entering `https://smwtest-15295.firebaseio.com/` into your browser, and you'll see the difference.